# C# XMLSerialization error, System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, invalidoperationexception

i'm new to XMLSerialization, and have nobody near to help me out with it, so here is a part of code i want to XMLSerialize/Deserialize, and an error itself.

I have a three classes:

```
public class Contacts
{
    public string country;
    public string city;
    public string street;
    public int houseNumber;
    public int flatNumber;
    public int phoneNumber;

    public Contacts(){...};

    public Contacts(string cntry, string city, string str, int houseNum, int flatNum, int phoneNum){...};
    public override string ToString(){...};
}

public class SimpleHuman
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int age;
    public string sex;
    public Contacts contacts;

    public SimpleHuman(){...};

    public SimpleHuman(string fn, string ln, int a, string s, Contacts c){...};

    public override string ToString(){...};
}

public class doctor : SimpleHuman
{
    public DateTime contractExpirationDate;
    public int idNumber;
    public List<int> doctorPatients;

    public doctor(){...};

    public doctor(string name, string surname, int age, string sex, int doctorID, Contacts c):base(name, surname, age, sex, c){...};

    public override string ToString(){...};
}
```

The problem is, when i'm trying to serialize class "doctor" into XML file with:

```
XmlSerializer SerializerDoc = new XmlSerializer(typeof(doctor));

foreach(doctor d in doctorList)
{
    TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter("doctors/" + d.firstName + d.lastName + ".xml");
    SerializerDoc.Serialize(WriteFileStream, d);

    WriteFileStream.Close();
}
```

i get this error on line with creating a TextWriter (translation from russina's below):

> "Необработанное исключение: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Clinic.doctor недос тупен в силу его уровня защиты. Возможна обработка
>   только общих типов.    в
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()    в
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo
>   source , Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)    в
>   System.Xml.Serialization.ModelScope.GetTypeModel(Type type, Boolean
>   directR eference)    в
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type
>   type,  XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace)    в
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String
>   defaultNames pace)    в
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)    в
>   Clinic.Clinic.saveDoctorInfo() в
>   d:\Dropbox\CSharpHomeWork\ExamTask\Clinic\ Program.cs:строка 833    в
>   Clinic.Clinic.launchMenu() в
>   d:\Dropbox\CSharpHomeWork\ExamTask\Clinic\Prog ram.cs:строка 463    в
>   Clinic.Program.Main(String[] args) в
>   d:\Dropbox\CSharpHomeWork\ExamTask\Cli nic\Program.cs:строка 870 Press
>   any key to continue . . ."

I have a russian version of WIN7, so the message on russian tells something like: "Unhandeled exception: .......: Clinic.doctor unavailable because of it's level of protection. It's possible to handle only a generic types."
   Translation's almost literal, so keep in mind.

Hope somebody will help me, because i can write class "doctor" with simple "XML Writer" but still it's none sense (as i think), as far as i can save it with one line, instead of 20.

Thanks guys.

**Upadte:** just did all of classes - public. Now i'm getting error on string: 
    TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter("doctors/" + d.firstName + d.lastName + ".xml");

```
It sais like:
```

Unhandled exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Failed to find part of path "D:\Dropbox\CSharpHomeWork\ExamTask\Clinic\bin\Debug\doctors\Anders
onNeo.xml".

Path is 100% correct. I just feel like instead of creating a file, it just tries to write something in already existing one.

BTW, sorry that i can't thank you with reputation up, because i can't do that now. But have my "verbal thanks" for now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` can only serialize public classes and members. Either make the `Doctor` and all its base classes `public class` or use a different serializer (e.g. `DataContractSerializer`).

Comment: Thanks, done. But now i have a new problem on same string of code. It seem not to find a specified path. Even if this path is 100% correct.

Comment: Does the doctors\ directory already exist? The StreamWriter won't create directories for you.

Comment: Now it's done... It just started to work after a system restart O_O      Thanks a lot, for your help.